# My update view isnt working when i submit the update form it dosent update the form

Tags: python, django

My update view isnt working when i submit the update form it dosent update the form. When i click the update button it just shows me the original post (unedited). if anyone could help  that would be great.

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        'post_list': posts
    }
    return render(request, "posts/post_list.html", context)


def post_detail(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    context = {
        'post': post
    }
    return render(request, "posts/post_detail.html", context)


def post_create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/posts')
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "form_type": 'Create'
    }
    return render(request, "posts/post_create.html", context)


def post_update(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/posts')
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "form_type": 'Update'
    }
    return render(request, "posts/post_create.html", context)
```

> urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import post_list, post_detail, post_create, post_update


urlpatterns = [
    path('', post_list),
    path('create/', post_create),
    path('<post_id>/', post_detail),
    path('<post_id>/update', post_update),
]
```

Comment: you can't render two views to a single html template , go check [render two views to a single html template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132010/render-two-views-to-a-single-html-template)

Comment: i am  following a youtube tutorial and it worked fine for him

Comment: yes you can render two views to a single template. This is where DRY principle takes place.

Comment: in your return HttpResponseRedirect('/posts') where have you specify the posts url. Check if its updating in you database.